Reverse Engineer an Intellisense alarm
I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to reverse engineer an intellisense alarm. When I look at the keypad it has four wires.

12-13.7 V
0 V
Clock
Data

The keypad itself has a PIC16C controller.  From what I can tell the clock is used to send data to the keypad for various functions, i.e. LEDs to represent the zones 1 to 8, power, tamper and operation (day or night) mode, along with beeps.
The data line is used when you pressed a button. 0-9 *#.

The circuit you see behind the keypad is so I can drive the keypad clock at 12 V from the 3.3 V output of the ESP. It's just two transistors, with some input filtering and resistors to limit current.
I'm trying to use an ESP8266 to act as a virtual keypad. When I use a logic analyser I get the following trace on the clock line.

It looks like there are 7 packets within what ever frame the manufacturer designed but this could be 8. I say this as the shortest pulse is 1.9 ms, if this was 2 ms it would be clocked at 500 Hz and sending 80 bits. I've tried this using 7 packets initially using a UART decoder with 9 bits, and it decodes. However if I send this back to the keypad, it doesn't light the LEDs as per the native control panel signal.
Has anyone experience with intellisense, or has seen a similar trace before?
As an update to this, I have tried framing the trace using the frequency that I have calculated based on the shorted pulse which is 1.9ms, this gives a frequency of 524Hz.  Ive tried decoding this with 8 and 9 bits for Data, 1,1.5 and 2 stop bits and also parity.  However depending on the control signal sent from the control panel, there is an extra bit that moves between what looks like the 7 frame.
in the attached pictures you can see this extra bit makes it look like the 1 frame, is 9 bits rather than 8, but then all the other frames are 8
This is when the alarm is unset

This is when the alarm is set

Here is another example, changing to 9 bit encoding, with 1-stop, and 1-parity.  However you can now see the 2nd frame doesnt decode.  From what I know about RS232, Start drags the signal low, and stop pushes it high.

but now when you look at the 6 frame, you can see there is an extra high pulse.

Your trace doesn't look like a clock to me.

@Blup1980, can you take a guess as to what you think the trace could be? I've tried bitbanging the serial line but I can't get the keypad to respond correctly.  I was thinking it could be pwm but then is that too complex for a pic16c?

Looks like 7 uart bytes sent with 2400 baud, probably 8N1.

@Jens - Thanks for having a look at this.  I originally started looking at a RS-232\UART decoder for this, but I cant seem to get the framing to align correctly for the 7 Bytes.  Ive tried it as 8 and 9 bits, 1,1.5 and 2 stop, and  varying degrees of parity, is a very odd framing format.
I say this because depending on the control signal sent from the control panel, there is an extra bit that moves between the 7 bytes.  Ill try and update the original post to add in the new traces that ive done.  Ive pulled them into a single picture
